# Comparing two boolean variables in JS

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement, boolean

I`m sending my form data with JQuery .ajax(), and i want to check if every input field is filled. But when i try to compare the boolean variables it is always getting in the else{} statement.

That`s is my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = $('.form').serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: '../php/data.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                if(response === true){
                    $('.result').html("Message sent!").css("color","green");                                
                } else{
                    $('.result').html("Please fill all fields").css("color","red");
                }
            }
        })
    })
});
```

And that`s the php:

```
<?php 
    $flag = true;

    $data = $_POST;

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        if ($row === '') {
            $flag = false;
        }
    }
    var_dump($flag);

 ?>
```

The question is what am i doing wrong???

Comment: What is the value of `response`? My PHP is rusty, but shouldn't `var_dump($flag)` be `print $flag` instead?

Comment: If you fill all the fields, the value is "bool(true)", otherwise it`s "bool(false)". The problem comes when i have to compare the response

Comment: `bool(true)` is not a valid JavaScript variable. If the result is the *string* `"bool(true)"` then that's a string and not a boolean.

Comment: You're using a normal AJAX call, which will return the content of that call as a string. In this case it will return `"bool(true)"`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware right, that's what I thought. So it needs to use `print` or whatever PHP operator is most appropriate that just outputs the value, not a debug version of the value.

Comment: @VLAZ: Yes, `print $flag;` or the more common `echo $flag;`. And the comparison should then be `if (strtolower(response) == "true")`. Personally I prefer the `$.getJSON()` AJAX call, which returns JSON, and can actually return a real boolean. In the PHP script you would have to use `json_encode(['allFilled' => $flag]);`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware `$.ajax()` should attempt to deserialise it into a boolean type. Although it might not. Depends a bit on which headers are sent over. You can always throw `JSON.parse()` if needed. Or set `dataType: "json"` to make jQuery automatically parse the response. PHP should also have `json_encode` that can be used on the returned value to make sure it's proper JSON - I can't remember what the string representation of a boolean is in PHP but encoding as JSON should handle it automatically.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I fully agree.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
echo $flag;
```

and not the `var_dump()` function. This one is only used for debugging purposes and shows you some data concerning the variable you will pass to it.